# One battery slot of a set kills its sitting battery

Tags: batteries

My kid has a battery-operated toy, it runs on three AAA batteries. Once, the toy suddenly stopped working, but all batteries were good. I decided to disassemble the toy and look for internal damage or some loose wire. Found nothing and reasembled it. The next day, on a last attempt before dumping it, I placed the batteries back on just to confirm, but it just started working again. Have no idea what changed. Humidity maybe?

Now the issue. Since then, the toy is killing one of the batteries in the pack, in a week or so. It stops working, I check the batteries, the one on the left is completely dead with 0 volts, the other ones are ok. I replace the dead battery, it gets back working ok. Another week or so, the toy stops working again, and the newly replaced battery is dead. It's always on the same deck position.

Never seen this happening and it didn't seem possible when using similar batteries, except if one was defective. But this isn't the case. The toy will always kill the battery on the left.

Any thoughts on this?

**(Edit)**

I thought the above was self-explanatory, sorry if not.
The three batteries sit side by side, but in serial on the circuit. One of the batteries depletes really fast. "Battery on the left" is only a visual reference, in practical means, it only represents that the battery that suffers the issue is always the one sitting on that specific slot.
I'll try to add some photos, maybe later today if I have the chance.

@Frog I thought that a short in one battery would affect them all. But maybe not, now I see. After examining the plates and springs, it doesn't seem possible to have o short here as they seem to be very far from each other. A short makes sense, but it should burn out the battery in less than a day. And I've re-examined the toy inside and can't seem any clue of a short.

@Kyle B I've replaced one single cell, because this one was 0 volt and and the other two looked ok. So, by replacing only this dead one by a new one, leaving the other two, and after a week, the new battery was dead and the other two not, it was the proof that the fault was not on the battery.
I've disassembled it again and I just can't find any clues on any damaged wire, pinched stuff, short anywhere, any damage on the board, anything.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Obviously there is a problem, but without details it's just anyone's guess.  Please edit your question and add as many details as possible that may be relevant to resolving this.

Comment: `battery on the left` is meaningless

Comment: I’ve seen something very similar elsewhere; the spring contacts were slightly deformed and could short one of the cells - for primary cells the short-circuit current was too low to make the fault obvious but with a NiMH cell the short was obvious because the cell became hot, and a close inspection confirmed my suspicions.  In multi-cell batteries the cells are typically in series without any trappings, so a short is the only thing that could cause one cell to fail prematurely.

Comment: Photos, especially with it disassembled would help.

Comment: You should never replace just a single cell.   Replace them all and see if it happens again.    Since you disassembled it, you may have pinched a battery wire upon reassembly....easy to spot by just looking for damaged wires

Comment: This question has now been superseded by [a later one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/551296/one-battery-slot-kills-its-sitting-battery) from the same user. Therefore since that one has more information than this one, and already has some answers, then despite the fact that it should not have been opened, it is that one which will remain active now, rather than trying to move all the information and answers back to here.